# Regex: Match, but don't include part of matched

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the text:

```
https://www.google.com/url?rct=3Dj\u0026sa=3Dt\u0026url=3Dhttps://rivesjournal.com/inside-track-trading-focus-on-shares-of-adobe-systems-inc-adbe/48453/\u0026ct=3Dga\u0026cd=3DCAEYASoTOT
```

I want to get the actual link:

```
https://rivesjournal.com/inside-track-trading-focus-on-shares-of-adobe-systems-inc-adbe/48453/
```

The `/=3Dhttps.*\//g` gets including `=3D`, but I want to get without it. How can I figure this out?

Here's the [regex](http://regexr.com/3fbfg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to prevent the first `http.*` substring from being matched by using a negative lookahead with a `^` anchor:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/ujBn5W/1)

```
(?!^)https:.*\/
```

This essentially matches `https:.*\/` as long as it isn't at the beginning of the string.

Snippet:

```js
var string = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=3Dj\u0026sa=3Dt\u0026url=3Dhttps://rivesjournal.com/inside-track-trading-focus-on-shares-of-adobe-systems-inc-adbe/48453/\u0026ct=3Dga\u0026cd=3DCAEYASoTOT';

console.log(string.match(/(?!^)https:.*\//)[0]);
```

---

However, the expression above won't cover all edge cases therefore the better option would be to just use a capturing group:

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/OHFKSH/1)

```
=3D(https.*\/)
```

Snippet:

```js
var string = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=3Dj\u0026sa=3Dt\u0026url=3Dhttps://rivesjournal.com/inside-track-trading-focus-on-shares-of-adobe-systems-inc-adbe/48453/\u0026ct=3Dga\u0026cd=3DCAEYASoTOT';

console.log(string.match(/=3D(https.*\/)/)[1]);
```

---

You can also use a negated character class, such as `[^\\]+` in order to match one or more non-`\` characters:

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/rgREaP/1)

```
=3D(https[^\\]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

make =3D as a positive lookbehind

```
(?<==3D)https.*\/
```

demo here : https://regex101.com/r/sHvRMA/2

**update:**

for javascript specific code, use [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
var str = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=3Dj\u0026sa=3Dt\u0026url=3Dhttps://rivesjournal.com/inside-track-trading-focus-on-shares-of-adobe-systems-inc-adbe/48453/\u0026ct=3Dga\u0026cd=3DCAEYASoTOT';
var reg = /=3D(https.*\/)/;
console.log(str.match(reg)[1]);
```

Comment: @wscourge missed reading the tag, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

this is a great resource for figuring out regex matches

http://regexr.com/

Comment: I suppose this fits well in the comment section

Comment: below 50 reputation, and question was How can I figure this out?

Comment: Now you won't have excuses next time!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used regex in Javascript, but I have used them extensively in bash, sh, ps and C# and from what I understand this is what you are looking for:

```
/=3D(http.*\/)\\
```

https://regex101.com/r/bupG3W/1

And for capturing the group inside the match

```
var myString = "something format_abc";
var myRegexp = /(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]); // abc
```

Comment: Did you try this? This still has `=3D` included.

Comment: Are you capturing the match or the inner group?
(see answer's edit)

Answer (score 0):

For those using regex with a language that supports a limited subset of features (like CMake) none of the other answers may work.  In this case, one option is to just capture the preceeding string (`=3D` in the OP's case), and then use a string operation to remove it from the rest of the match after the fact.  It's not elegant, but it works.